# Remote Debugging On Android Browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, debugging, remote-debugging

Sorry for the question.

I'm current creating Phaser games for mobile using web browsers.

I can remote debugging on my android device using Google Chrome Browser of my android device also similar to Mozilla Firefox Browser and check if any error in javascript/html/css using the desktop developer tools of the browser.

Here is what i follow to use remote debugging for chrome
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Here for Mozilla Firefox

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Firefox_for_Android

Already installed Android SDK

I'm currently developing on windows platform.
Using XAMPP

But i want to test now my app on the native browser of android phones gives me hard time to do it. and don't have any idea on how to do it.

If anyone has done it before.. Kindly please share knowledge on how you to do it and make it easy and comfortable for yourself to remote debugging native android browser.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer?

Comment: it does have seem to  that option, but i think you might need the android sdk to connect.

Comment: I've been searching for a little while... and I found this: http://www.broken-links.com/2013/06/28/remote-debugging-with-weinre/ I'm personally testing this out and if it works I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this will only work if you have a local version of the website deployed... and your phone must be connected to the same network.

For reference, I used this website: http://www.broken-links.com/2013/06/28/remote-debugging-with-weinre/

First, you'll need to install NodeJS as weinre is a NodeJS app.

After you install Node, you can use NPM to install weinre.

```
npm install -g weinre
```

Then you start weinre server on your local machine

```
weinre --boundHost -all-
```

Then paste the following code in your webpage that you want to debug. Change `your_private_ip` to the private IP of your local server. It probably starts with `192.168.x.x`.

```
<script src="http://your_private_ip:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
```

Now on your desktop, go to http://localhost:8080/client/#anonymous to see a WebKit-style web inspector.

You should see something like this:[image: weinre ui]

Now you can use the other tabs like the Console to view the javascript console, or the elements to look at their styling, etc... just like on chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need help, but for those who are having this trouble can try this, it worked for me:

Do the exact same thing like you were to debug from google chrome, in the "chrome://inspect/#devices" tab look for this: WebView in com.android.browser (Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0) (in my case, i'm using a huawei p7)[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncQ1V.jpg)

Sorry for my english